# I have just activated php in my macbook but its saying something permission error

Tags: php, activation

I just activated php in macbook but when i try to access local host in browser it is saying `You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Can any one guid me properly what is getting wrong with this.
plus when i am editing httpd.conf file in terminal i can not find some by doing command plus w.

Comment: It's trying to tell you you don't have the rights to look at folders, but not a webpage. This means your server does not know which file to show when you don't specify it in the URL. Do you know which webserver engine you're using? Probably one of Apache or Nginx. Whichever it is, you need to configure it to use an index.php file.

Comment: Please provide much more details, this error can have a lot of reasons. There are also a lot of questions in Stack Overflow regarding this error. Did you go through them and try to fix it yourself? Did you google and go through the possibles fixes?

Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask again.

Comment: @BenHillier i also setup the php page and tried to access that but same error